# Swift: Cannot convert value of type 'Range<Int>' to specified type 'Int'

Tags: swift, xcode, syntax

I was trying to implement a small iteration which returns the square of some ranges.

Which should be the equivalence of this Python script

```
for i in range(n):
    print(i*i)
```

In Swift I tried

**first attempt**

```
let numbers = [1..<10]

for i in numbers{
    print(i*i)
}
```

and

**second attmpt**

```
let numbers = [1..<10]

for i in numbers{
    var j: Int = i
    print(j*j)
}
```

but then the compiler says
`Cannot convert value of type 'Range<Int>' to specified type 'Int'`

I understand from my python experience this is due to different types in Swift. Thus my questions are

1. How can I fix this? (i.e. implement the same thing i did in python)
2. What are the problems with my first and second attempts?
3. Why are there so many types of `<Int>` in Swift?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Why are there so many types of `<Int>` in Swift?" umm where did that come from? You've only mentioned `Range<Int>` in your question, and _one_ isn't "many"...

Comment: By the way, why did you decide to enclose the `1..<10` in `[]`? Removing them would have made both of your codes work.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading term, from a shallow search on the internet i saw Range<Int>, ClosedRange<Int> and so on. These are the 'many' `<Int>` I mean.

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks! That works! I thought when generating an array we must have `[]` around them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't compile because you have used `[]` around the range, which creates an array. `[1..<10]` is an *array* of ranges. The for loop is then iterating over that array, which has only one element - the range `1..<10`.

This is why `i` is of type `Range<Int>`. It is the range, not the numbers in the range.

Just remove the `[]` and both of your code would work. You can iterate over ranges directly (in fact, anything that conforms to the [`Sequence`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence) protocol), not just arrays. You can even write the range inline with the loop:

```
for i in 0..<10 {
    print(i * i)
}
```

> Why are there so many types of `<Int>` in Swift?

You are looking at this the wrong way, the word `Range` and `ClosedRange` in the types `Range<Int>` and `ClosedRange<Int>` are not words that modify `Int`, as if they are different "flavours" of `Int`. It's the opposite - [`Range<Bound>`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/range) and [`ClosedRange<Bound>`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/closedrange) are [generic types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html), and `Range<Int>` can be a considered the specific "type" of `Range` that has `Int` as its bounds. You can also have `Range<Float>` or `Range<UInt8>` for example.